# How to access a class field in a complicated chain of classes

Tags: java, android, constructor-chaining

My class A creates in its constructor an instance of class B. Class B's constructor creates an instance of its inner class C. Class C needs a field in its constructor from class A and here is the problem. Class C reaches only the default value of the field of A.

I initialize the value of the field of A in A's constructor before starting the initiation of B and C.  I checked that the field has the value I need.  Nevertheless, the value of that field in the constructor of C is always the default one. 
I am not sure how to deal with this. Any help?

Thanks!

Thank you guys for all answers! I felt though that more information is necessary.

This is part of my class A: The problematic variables are startX and startY. I defined them in the constructor either directly, ether through setter method. 
Class B is DrawView. Class C is DrawThread. 
I do not know how to pass arguments to the constructor of DrawView, otherwise I would. Help?
Another option is to use /*display = ((WindowManager)       getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

in DrawView or DrawThread to set my startX and startY, but it just does not want to work. 
This really switches my question more to android now, and I will be grateful for any suggestions how to get screen size in the constructor of DrawThread, which was the ultimate goal of all that:)?

public class ColorAnimation extends Activity {

```
    public static float startX;

    public static float startY;

             //other stuff here

             @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // turn off the window's title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // tell system to use the layout defined in our XML file
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        startX = display.getWidth();
        startY = display.getHeight();*/

        mDrawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.pend);
        mDrawThread = mDrawView.getThread();

        // give the DrawView a handle to the TextView used for messages
        mDrawView.setTextView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));
```

Constructor of class B:

//

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

```
    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(this);

    thread = new DrawThread(holder, context, new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
            mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    });

    setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events
}
```

//part of class C DrawThread:

class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

```
    class DrawThread extends Thread {//................
         //..............


    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
            Handler handler) {
        // get handles to some important objects
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mHandler = handler;
        mContext = context;
```

Comment: Hmm... Can you give us some code? Maybe just take those portions of the classes that are relevant to what you're asking, with or without the A-B-C name abstractions. Because it kind of sounds like it should work properly.

Comment: yep, the code is above but things became more android now than java

Answer (score 3):

Until the constructor for class A is completed (which means the constructors for B and C have completed), its best to assume that you don't have access to a fully-constructed and populated instance of A.  You should pass down the value you're setting to A.field into the constructor for class B and reference it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function in class A that accesses the value of field A. Then just pass the instance of class A all the way down to class C. Without more details, I don't think I can give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a *class* field then it should work. This SSCCE always returns "A SET IT".

```
class A {

    public static String VALUE = "default";

    public A() {
        VALUE = "A SET IT";
        B b = new B();
    }

}

class B {

    public B() {
        C c = new C();
    }

    public static class C {
        public C() {
            String value = A.VALUE;
            System.out.print(value);
        }
    }
}


public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

If the value you're trying to access is really an *object* field (i.e. not `static`), this isn't the case - the object isn't really created until the constructor completes.

There may be other things affecting this in your specific case - classloaders, threads, etc. that you didn't mention.

Comment: Where you went wrong (and this is the gotcha...) his class C was an anonymous inner class, which might get called whenever.  But he constructed it with A.field, which at the time of construction, was undefined in B.  The spec says don't use A until after C... C was initialized with an uninitialized A (according to the OPs post), so A.field is technically undefined.

Comment: In other words, you can't pass `this` down to a class you're instantiating when you're within `this`'s constuctor and expect consistent results unless you're really careful.

Comment: @Chris Well spotted! I wouldn't have expected this behaviour. Something to remember.

Comment: @Chris That's covered in the "if the value you're trying to access is really an object field" after the example code.  I can't really tell at all what the OP really wants because there's too much extraneous code and parts left out (I don't see where he's even trying to access the static fields he's created...).  I'm assuming the "real problem" is that he's trying to access view properties before the Activity is visible - he should be doing this in 'onStart()' instead of 'onCreate()'.

Comment: I access the static fields in the constructor of DrawThread by calling them with the class name: this.startX = ColorAnimation.startX. I think my problem is actually not just java constructors issue, but it interferes with android's onCreate methods. I still don't know how to solve it for now.